# Magento tells me to apply modified catalog price rules but there are no rules at all

Tags: catalog-price-rules, messages

I noticed a message in `Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules`:

"There are rules that have been changed but were not applied. Please, click Apply Rules in order to see immediate effect in the catalog."

But I couldn't see any rule at all. Not in backend, not in database. All these tables were empty:

```
catalogrule
catalogrule_affected_product
catalogrule_customer_group
catalogrule_group_website
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_product_price
catalogrule_website
```

I cleared cache and ran a full reindex but the message still showed up. Only hitting the "Apply" button made the message disappear. Now I'm wondering where Magento pulls this information (that rules still need to get applied) if it does not pulling it from catalogrule* table. Do anyone know ?

Comment: Open your phpmyadmin and execute following query: SELECT `core_flag`.* FROM `core_flag` WHERE (`core_flag`.`flag_code`='catalog_rules_dirty') Then show us result. Most probably existed flag force your error.

Comment: Thanks! Thats how it works! There is indeed an entry in core_flag with state=0 and flag_data=NULL. I assume its save to delete this row?

Comment: Yes, I think both variants are suitable

Comment: Hi, i know this is an older post, but I followed these directions after my rules wouldn't apply as well.  I found in Magento 2.1, there is a flag table and there is an entry with catalog_rules_dirty.  Can you explain this?  There is nothing on Google that I could find about this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove flag

```
SELECT core_flag.* FROM core_flag WHERE (core_flag.flag_code='catalog_rules_dirty')
```