# Magento 2 : What is The _flag Table in Database

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, catalog-price-rules

I have a problem with Catalog Price Rules not being applied in my store.  Some work and some don't.  I have searched for solution, and I finally found one that I have never heard of before.

[Magento tells me to apply modified catalog price rules but there are no rules at all](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76257/magento-tells-me-to-apply-modified-catalog-price-rules-but-there-are-no-rules-at)

I have searched but could not find any description of the flag table and what it does, or does not do.  If deleting an entry in this table fixes the price rules, then Magento is doing a terrible job of explaining things, such as this table.

Can someone explain the flag table, or point me to a reference that explains the table and codes found in it?

Comment: Amit and Dhiren, thanks for the edits, by any chance do you have anything to contribute to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Flag table is used to store some simple data that doesn’t change much, isn’t user defined, and doesn’t warrant creating its own table

You can follow http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2014/02/27/save-simple-data-magento-flags/ to read how to use in Magento 1
or http://www.magegyver.de/using-flag-models-in-magento-2/ to read how to use Flag Model in Magento 2

Functions of Flag Model are in \Magento\Framework\Flag file

Note: If you can't find table core_flag in your DB, you can find table flag instead of. Name of flag table is declared in \Magento\Framework\Flag\FlagResource file

Comment: Tigren, i appreciate the answe, however I was asking more what the table entries do to the Magento 2 system.  What do the entries mean?  For example "catalog_rules_dirty".  What does this entry mean?  Is there a problem with my Catalog Price Rules?